# Java Sockets - Sending an object from the server and receiving/displaying it to the client

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I am trying to send an object from my server and then receiving it/displaying it on the client side. The object in question has a few parameters tied to it, such as int values and string values. Do I also need to have a version of my server class on the client side in which to store the values from the input stream?

I have tried the following:

**Server**

```
public void run() {
        int height = 6;
        int width = 9;
        int moves = height * width;

        System.out.println("Connected: " + socket);

        try {
            Server server = new Server(val1, val2, str1, str2);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

//          while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
//              printWriter.println(scanner.nextInt());
//          }

            System.out.println(server );
//          printWriter.println(server );
            serverOutputStream.writeObject(server );

//          while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            for (int player = 0; moves-- > 0; player = 1 - player) {
                char symbol = PLAYERS[player];

                server.doSomething(symbol, scanner);

//              printWriter.println(scanner.nextInt());
                System.out.println(server);
//              printWriter.println(server);
                serverOutputStream.writeObject(server);

                if (server.hasWon()) {
                    System.out.println("\nPlayer " + symbol + " wins!");

                    return;
                }
//              }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + socket);
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            System.out.println("Closed: " + socket);
        }
    }
```

***Client***

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//        if (args.length != 1) {
//            System.err.println("Pass the server IP as the sole command line argument");
//            
//            return;
//        }

        try (Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 59898)) {
            System.out.println("Enter a move: ");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            Object object = serverInputStream.readObject();

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                serverOutputStream.writeObject(object);
            }
        }
    }
```